# Does reduceByKey called on a DStream reduces input data across all the batches, or only across the batch being processed?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a Spark Streaming application that consumes data from AWS Kinesis.

```
      val dStream = allStreams
        .transform(rdd => {
          rdd.flatMap(func1(_))
        }).reduceByKey((acc, next) => acc.aggregate(next))
```

My question is: Does the application perform 'reduceByKey' on each batch in an isolated way, or does it aggregate over all the batches?
For example, let's say it's a word counter and batch 1 arrives that has 3 occurrences of 'word1'. Batch 2 has 5 occurrences of 'word1'. So if I send the result downstream in each batch, what would the results be? Would they be
Batch 1: word1 -> 3 occurrences
Batch 2: word1 -> 5 occurrences
Or would it be:
Batch 1: word1 -> 3 occurrences
Batch 2: word1 -> 8 occurrences

I've tried looking up the documentation but I haven't been able to find anything that specifically addresses this.